# How can I make a discord timeout command with discord.net C#

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

Im trying to make a Discord C# Command That uses Discords new Timeout function using discord.NET

I tried using HTTP Requests instead cause i couldnt find a discord.NET function but It returns an unauthorized error

```
public static async Task PatchData(string url, string data, string token)
{
    // Create a new HttpClient instance
    using var httpClient = new HttpClient();
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Authorization",token);
    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    var content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
    var response = await httpClient.PatchAsync(url, content);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Data patched successfully!");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
    }
}
```

and for the execution

```
await Patch.PatchData($"https://discord.com/api/v9/guilds/{Context.Guild.Id}/members/{user.Id}", 
    "{\"communication_disabled_until\": " 
    + current_time + time_in_minutes + "}",botToken);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a special awaitable for this

```
var time = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0);
await Your_IGuildUser.SetTimeOutAsync(span: time);
```

Check if you are updated to the lastest version.

Also i think discord usually will not accept random HTTP request resulting in authorized error but it is just my assumption.